# How to use &amp; in nginx conf

Tags: php, xml, nginx

I have a developed website running on nginx + php + Ubuntu.  Recently I have developed an automated xml site map generation script.  It generates sitemap.xml for all the url which are associate with website.

In my website some urls contains argument.

Ie.

[www.mywebsite.com/?arg1=a&arg2=b&arg3=c](http://mywebsite.com/?q=arg1=a&arg2=b&arg3=c)

But this type of url cannot be include in sitemap.xml, because **&** is not accepted in XML. Instead of that I have replace **&** by **& amp;** which is totally valid for XML.

But this modification effect for my Nginx conf file, because Nginx does not accept “escaped” characters thus **& amp;** does not working for use GET request.

Is there any way to solve this riddle?
Any suggestions or solutions most welcome.

Comment: it's the job of the sitemap crawler to unescape &amp; in & (and other special chars). Which bot is sending you bad requests? Or are you testing it yourself?

Comment: regilero : it is nginx end issue